# Selecting an area for scaling Echarts Angular

Tags: angular, echarts

There is an [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-draggable) from the official documentation. As you can see here, when the mouse cursor is selected, the data area is shown.

I just can't figure out how to do this in angular. A similar echarts config gives the following: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/echarts-demo-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Flinechart.component.ts).
Here you can see that you cannot select an area with the mouse cursor, but only drag the slider.

Any help, thanks!

**UPDATE** 
I want to select the area with the mouse cursor in the same way as in the echarts example.

[image]

Comment: You might want to be more specific about what you want to do.  As far as I can tell your stackblitz demo works perfectly fine.  What exactly isn't happening here that you want to happen?

Comment: @Optiq I supplemented the question, please see

Comment: ok so which example is yours?  The first one?  are you trying to figure out how to make it so the user can't move the points?

Comment: @Optiq I'm trying to figure out how to make it work like the example from the official documentation. I want to select the required area with the cursor, and not just move it.

Answer (score 0):

Area selection on the zoom slider is available only from echarts v5.0. Try updating the package version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).